# Entity Framework - Response Validation Errors with StateModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a web api method that creates/insets a new entity into database:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("object/create")]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateNewObject([FromBody]MyObject object)
{
    try{
        MyService service = new MyService();
        service.createObject(object);
    }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex){
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Validation Erros occured");
    }
}
```

The `service.createObject(object)` reads the foreign keys, double checks if the foreign keys are valid and loads/add the foreign entities to have the object-entity complete. After that it calls `context.saveChanges()`. In case of validation errors, `DbEntityValidationException` is thrown:

```
public Object createObject(Object object){
    object.foreignObject = context.foreignObjects.where(e => e.id == object.foreignObject.id).First();
    context.Objects.Add(object);
    context.saveChanges();
}
```

So far so good. Having this setup the problem is that I only response a "Validation Errors Occured" that is not handable in frontend.

So my question is, if there is any way to parse the `DbEntityValidationException` to `ModelState` that can be responded?

Comment: ModelState is an MVC concept. So it's not available in WebAPI (and `CreateNewObject` looks like a WebAPI action method).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all information you need in catch block and return it in response in format you want to present.

Comment: Ok. That sounds like there is no "standard" respectively "default" approach for that? I hoped that there is something like ModelState so that I don't need to do all that stuff manually :(